# Derivative $\frac{1 }{ x \ln(x)^p}$

Tags: calculus

Section 11.3 Q 25 James Stewart's Calculus text book we are required to take the derivative of:
$$\frac{1}{x\ln(x)^p},$$
where $p$ is a real number, in order to prove that the function is decreasing, so that the integral test can be used.

The solution given is:

$$- \frac{p + \ln(x)}{x^2 \ln(x)^{p+1}}$$

This means the derivative of $x\ln(x)^p = p+\ln(x)$, assuming quotient rule is used.

However I cant see how this is derived, is this where I am going wrong?

[From book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqVni.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The quotient rule can be used, but terms cancel too. Note that your denominator isn't the square of the original fraction's denominator. Use the chain rule to differentiate $(\ln(x))^p$.

Comment: So apply quotient rule as you say. Right, I think OP confused about this, Chris

Comment: It's not decreasing in general.  If we are requiring $x>1$ then both $x$ and $\left(\ln x\right)^p$ are positive and increasing so the reciprocal of the product is decreasing in that region.  No derivative required.

Answer (score -1):

If you differentiate $x\ln(x)^p$, what you get is
$$
x'\ln(x)^p+xp\ln'(x)\ln(x)^{p-1}=\ln(x)^p+p\ln(x)^{p-1}.
$$
Therefore, if you differentiate $\frac1{x\ln(x)^p}$, you get
$$
-\frac{\ln(x)^p+p\ln(x)^{p-1}}{x^2\ln(x)^{2p}}=-\frac{\ln(x)+p}{x^2\ln(x)^{p+1}}.
$$

Comment: I would note that the OP wrote the solution incorrectly, maybe that was their problem.